# Integrate the 0Auth/google to the react-redux project

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux, google-oauth

I'm developing a social media app using React and have integrated Redux for state management. Now, I want to add Google OAuth login functionality using the @react-oauth/google package.

The problem is that the @react-oauth/google package requires wrapping my  component with its GoogleOAuthProvider, like this:

```
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="<your_client_id>">
<App />
</GoogleOAuthProvider>;
```

However, I've already wrapped my app with the Provider from react-redux like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How can I wrap my  component with both the Provider from react-redux and the GoogleOAuthProvider from @react-oauth/google simultaneously to use both state management and Google OAuth functionality in my app?

I tried to use the `react-google-login` package, but eventually it throws me errors like:

```
{error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}

details: 
"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that are deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error
: 
"idpiframe_initialization_failed"
```

and

```
error: "popup_closed_by_user"
```